# How to replace a ' from a String in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to remove a " ' " character from a python string .
Below code gives a syntax error, How to achieve this task

```
final = string.replace(old_str, '\'', '')
```

Comment: When you want to mention a single quote `'`, use double quotes `"'"`, and vice versa `'"'`. also the `replace` method is wrongly used: `final = old_str.replace("'", '')`

Comment: Can show what  ```old_str``` is?

Comment: This snippet shouldn't raise a `SyntaxError`. Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Comment: There should only be two parameters in the `string.replace()` function

Answer (score 1):

To replace single quotes

```
final = old_str.replace("'", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

`str = "this is string example....wow!!! this is really string"
print(str.replace("is", "was"))`

Here's an example of how to correctly use the `replace` function. This replaces all the is's with was's. It's hard to see what you're trying to do but use this as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
string = "some ' string"
final = string.replace('\'','')
print(final)
```

**output**

```
some  string
```